# Space between Number and Text

Tags: microsoft-excel

Hi I am looking for help i currently have the following in excel A1= 50-100LSER
I am looking for a formula to replace the - with space and add a space between the 100 and LSER

Can someone help please

Answer (score 3):

This replaces the `-` with `" "` and finds the first non number and puts a `" "` in front of it:

```
=REPLACE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"-"," "),MIN(IF(NOT(ISNUMBER(--MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"-",0),ROW(INDIRECT("1:" & LEN(A1))),1))),ROW(INDIRECT("1:" & LEN(A1))))),0," ")
```

This is an array formula and must be entered as such.  It needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.  If done correctly then Excel will put `{}` around the formula.

[image]